# Angular $http executes function "success" instead of "error"

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth

my Angular client calls a web api function which checks if the user is authorized by password and user name. Here is the relevant beginning of the method:

```
        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.Get<DividendsManagerUserManager>();

        if (allowedOrigin == null) allowedOrigin = "*";

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

        var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Der Benutzername oder das Passwort ist ungültig.");
            return;
        }
```

As you see, I use context.SetError in case the provided login is invalid. Doing so returns this message as seen in Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 12:49:10 GMT
Content-Length: 97

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Der Benutzername oder das Passwort ist ungültig."}

Looks good to me. But in Angular, the api call "succeeds", because the success function callback is executed:

```js
        var _login = function(loginData) {

            var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password + "&client_id=" + authSettings.clientId;

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).success(function(response) {

                localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName, refreshToken: response.refresh_token, useRefreshTokens: true });

                fillAuthData();

                deferred.resolve(response);

            }).error(function(err, status) {
                _logOut();
                deferred.reject(err);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Anyone knows what wents wrong?

Regards,

Torsten

P.S.: Within the success function I could check if the response contains an error. But that feels like a bad hack.

Comment: Which angularjs version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.5.8.

Comment: Can you test using `.then(...).catch(...)` instead of `.success(...).error(...)`? Those methods are deprecated on this version of angularjs.

Comment: I just found the source of the error. I wrote an interceptor. My intention was just to set a property of a service I injected into the interceptor. Because of this, I just did not manipulate the rejection in any way and just passed it through like this:

function responseError(rejection) {
            busyService.isBusy = true;

            return rejection;
        }

But this seems to make the $http.post a success.

If I do this:

Comment: It makes sense. Also, consider returing the `$http` promise directly, you don't have to create a deferred for that, you can do `return $http.post(...).then(function (response) { return response.data; });`

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In a promise chain, rejections can be **converted** to success **by returning** values to the rejection handler. This makes it possible to fix problems and retry an operation. But it can also lead to bugs related to unwanted conversions.

```
promise.then(function successHandler(value) {
    //return to chain value
    return value;
}).catch(function rejectHandler(errorValue) {
    //to avoid conversion
    //throw to chain rejection
    throw errorValue;
    //OR return rejected promise
    //return $q.reject(errorValue);
});
```

One of the most common causes of unwanted conversions is failing to return or throw anything:

```
//ERRONEOUS
function responseError(errorResponse) {
    console.log(errorResponse.status);
}
```

In the above example, the rejection handler erroneously converts the rejection to a success. When a function omits either a `return` statement or a `throw` statement, the function returns `undefined`. This causes the rejection to be converted to a success that resolves with a value of `undefined`.

So when debugging erroneous convertions, check the rejection handlers. Then look for a badly behaving interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the source of the error. I wrote an interceptor. My intention was just to set a property of a service I injected into the interceptor. Because of this, I just did not manipulate the rejection in any way and just passed it through like this:

```js
function responseError(rejection) {
            busyService.isBusy = true;

            return rejection;
        }
```

But this seems to make the $http.post a success.

If I do this the $http.post is an error (as wanted):

```js
        function responseError(rejection) {
            busyService.isBusy = true;

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.reject(rejection);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

I still don't know why and will have to further investigate. If someone can further explain, this would be nice.